# How to map USB button to act as the "Enter" key?

Tags: usb, accessibility, button

I ordered [USB foot pedal/button](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Foot-Control-Action-Switch-Pedal-Free-Driver-HID-for-Keyboard-Mouse-Game-PC-Laptop/32805974553.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3fTqNL). Currently it outputs the letter "B" when pressed. How to make it act as the key "Enter"?

Comment: Why do you post the same question again instead of editing the original one? https://askubuntu.com/q/941659/631600

Comment: That other question has been removed, can the exact duplicate marking be eliminated?

Comment: @LucasW I voted to reopen (as other one was deleted)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide: http://h6o6.com/2013/03/configure-a-usb-foot-pedal-on-linux/ (this is a transcription of this documentation).

1. find out how the foot pedal is addressed by the operating system with `lsusb`, e.g. `Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0c45:7403 Microdia`
2. get more details with `lsusb -v -d 0c45:7403 | grep "idVendor|idProduct"` where `0c45:7403` is the device ID that shows up in lsusb
3. find how the USB foot pedal is addressed as an input device so that we can remap it: `/lib/udev/findkeyboards` (e.g. `USB keyboard: input/event11`)
4. `sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event11` (If you accidentily choose your primary keyboard, press ESC to get back to the command prompt.)
5. there you can see the scan code that is detected when the foot pedal is pressed, e.g. `0x70005`
6. edit (sudo) `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules` to append:

   `ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Microdia", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x7403", RUN+="keymap $name microdia"
   LABEL="keyboard_end"`

   Very important note here, the `ID_VENDOR` is set to our result from `lsusb` before while the `idProduct` matches the `0x7403` we got again from `lsusb` and it comes just before the line `LABEL="keyboard_end"`.
7. create a new keymap file at `/lib/udev/keymaps/microdia` (substituting your `LABEL` from before as the filename): `0x70005 F13` (Mapping the <kbd>F13</kbd> to the pedal).
8. run the command to get it up and running: `sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event11 /lib/udev/keymaps/microdia`.
   Note that you will need to reboot your machine for the change to be permanent, but otherwise you should be good.

Hope it helps :)